# How to fix edged Signed Distance Fields output?

Tags: fonts, opengl-es

I try to render some text/font with OpenGL ES 2.0 and Signed Distance Fields. I create a SDF Bitmap for a font and can render some text to the screen, but the displayed text is very edged.

Here you can see a part of my Signed Distance Field Input: [Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo47M.png)

Here you can see my output on screen: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LG2E.png)

Generate Texture and fill with Bitmap:

```
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
    GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);
    GL.GenTextures(1, out TextureId); 
    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureId); GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int) TextureMinFilter.NearestMipmapLinear);
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int) TextureMagFilter.Linear);
    GL.GenerateMipmap(TextureTarget.Texture2D);
    GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget2d.Texture2D,0,TextureComponentCount.Rgba,Width,Height,0,PixelFormat.Rgba,PixelType.UnsignedByte,ImageData);
    GL.GenerateMipmap(TextureTarget.Texture2D);
```

Fragment Shader:

```
void main() 
{   
    float distance = texture2D(tex_object, tc).a;
    float alpha = smoothstep(0.5 - 0.05, 0.5 + 0.05, distance); 
    fragColor = vec4(fColor.rgb, fColor.a * alpha);
}
```

Shader is correct compiled and values are passed correct, because letters are displayed. 
Does somebody know how to fix this and make it smoother?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @BDL code added

Answer (score 1):

You're using NearestMipmapLinear where you should be using LinearMipmapNearest.

NearestMipmapLinear is smoothly interpolating between mipmap levels, and doing point filtering within mips.

LinearMipmapNearest is point filtering between mipmap levels and bilinear filtering within mips.

Comment: when I change the TextureMinFilter, this doesn't make a difference. NearestMipmapLinear and LinearMipmapNearest looks nearly the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
float alpha = smoothstep(0.5 - 0.05, 0.5 + 0.05, distance);
```

Try different values for the edges of your smoothstep, that is, change the - 0.05 and + 0.05.